# What is the Matlab install directory on 64bit or how to get it in Python?

Tags: python, matlab

I have Matlab2013b on my system at :

> C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin

I am writing Python script that searches for Matlab.exe first at this location and then at location for 64 bit.
The Python script  will be run on a server which might have a 64 bit instead of 32 bit. So, I need to search for both locations.
Since I don't have 64 bit version on my machine, I don't know the location.

I am speculating it will be:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2013b\bin

But can anybody confirm that?
Thanks
sedy

Comment: If you don't have Matlab 64bit you don't have that path, so why do you let python search for it?

Comment: Probably that one. On windows machines using x64 processors there are 2 `Program Files`. The  one for 32 bits is called `Program Files (x86)`. However, it depends where the user has installed Matlab

Comment: @thewaywewalk  please see my updated question

Comment: 64-bit applications for Windows are stored in `Program Files` while 32-bit applications are stored in `Program Files (x86)`.  This is what is *traditionally* done.  It'll be up to the user to decide where the application is being stored.  Also, you can't just rely on the directory name to delineate which version of MATLAB that is installed.  You're going to have to do some extra work because what if the user installs MATLAB in another location?  How would you infer if the 32-bit or 64-bit version was installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read out the environment variable **PATH** (I'd say it's quite sure *MATLAB* it's included) and use some string operations to get the Matlab path:

```
import os
path = os.environ.get('path')
pathlist = path.split(';')
matlabpath = [s for s in pathlist if all(x in s for x in ['MATLAB','R','bin'])]
print(matlabpath)
```

this way you don't need to *speculate* what I would consider a generally bad programming practice.

---

In my case there is also an toolbox **polyspace** on the same path, you need to exclude that:

```
matlabpath = [s for s in pathlist if all(x in s for x in ['MATLAB','R','bin']) and not 'polyspace' in s]
```

There may be other toolboxes writing itself into **path** - it could be cumbersome to exclude all of them, so the easiest would be to just return the shortest of all Matlab related paths:

```
import os
path = os.environ.get('path')
pathlist = path.split(';')
matlabpath = min([s for s in pathlist if 'MATLAB' in s], key=len) 
print(matlabpath)
```

Comment: Hi thewaywewalk: excellent response. One question though, right now, running on my system gives _matlabpath _  as list with 2 results, _matlabpath[0] is _'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\runtime\win64'_ and  _matlabpath[1]_ is _'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\bin'_ . Would 32 bit path be added as 2 more elements?